# curious behaviour of a located struct

Tags: c++, struct

I found a courious *struct* in a foreign software:

```
*struct YINIT yInit = 
{
  "bla", "miao", 1, 0, (uint16_t[])
    {
     SWAPINT(0x200)
    }
};*
```

I don't check this, and I didn't seen before.
Can you help for understandig this?

My problem is, compiler spits a warning message:
*deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'*

But without understanding I cannot help my compiler...

Comment: This is a declaration of a variable of type `struct YINIT`. Check out your roots and how the `C` language part of `C++` works.

Comment: Please show the definition of `YINIT`. And remove the asterisks if they're used for emphasis and not present in the actual code.

Comment: First two parameters should be declared as `const char*` in `YINIT` structure.

Answer (score 1):

This declares and initializes a variable of type `struct YINIT`. You didn't show the definition of the struct, but the error is quite clear.

The struct has members of type `char*` and those members are initialized with string literals. Prior to C++11 such conversion was merely deprecated, hence the warning. Since C++11 such conversion is ill-formed and the compiler may choose to not accept it at all.

Solution: Change the type of the members to `const char*`, or don't initialize them to point to string literals.

Comment: There is a third possibility: `const_cast<char*>("bla")`. This is horrid, but if you can't fix the definition of `YINIT`, it may be the least painful solution.